# Nuxt Build PostScc Syntax error line 1 on scss component

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, scss-lint

I have a node 18.7.0 project that uses nuxt 2.15.8. I have the following scss code inside my vue component

```
<style lang="scss">

.Accordion {
  --Accordion__margin-top: 2.5rem;
   &__items {
        margin-top: calc(var(--Accordion__margin-top) * -1);
    }
  }
</style>
```

When I run a nuxt build I get a postcss error with not much detail except

> syntax error at line 1

If I change simply the line like so it works

```
margin-top: var(--Accordion__margin-top);
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a new variable $margin-top

then updated the problem line as follows

```
$margin-top :2.5rm;
`margin-top: calc(margin-top * -1);`
```